# Enable full disk access for an application without a .app extension

Tags: macos, security

I'm trying to mess around with the circuit design application "Digital" but it doesn't seem to be able to read data from folders. I tried giving it access in system preferences, but it doesn't seem to allow me to add .jar applications. This might not be the issue, but it seems like the most probable cause. If allowing all applications full disk access would fix it, I'd be ok with the security hit. I'm on the latest version of digital installed with homebrew. I'm on M1, if that's relevant.

Comment: It'd be terminal or Java - however you are launching it wouldn't it?

Comment: I was just launching by double-clicking. It says it's opening with JavaLauncher.app, but a finder search doesn't find anything by that name

Comment: launching it from terminal fixed the problem, thanks! For the future, is there any easy way to allow every application full disk access?